# Isomorphism between two sets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the additive group of all real numbers, and let $G_0$ be the group of all
positive real numbers under multiplication.

So I defined the following map $\phi(x) = 10^x$ and I proved its well defined and one to one and homomorphic, but for onto I don't know it seems very obvious can I just say:

For any positive real number $y \in G`$, we can find real number 
$x \in G$ such that $10^x = y$ would that be rigorous enough ? I have sometimes a lot of troubles proving rigorously that a function is onto if someone could clarify that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=\log_{10} y$, or $\frac{\ln y}{\ln 10}$.

Comment: I see so it works like this if we assume that $log(y) \in G$ we know its in G by the argument I presented above so we can pick $x = log_10(y)$ and so $\phi(x) = y$ and since y is arbitrarily so $\phi(x) = y$ so this should we can generate any y in the codomain yes makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Some calculus background is needed. The function $\phi$ you have defined is increasing and continuous. Furthermore,
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\phi(x)=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)=\infty$$
 This shows, with the help of the intermediate value theorem, that $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_{>0}$ is bijective. [Its inverse is, of course, $\log_{10}(\cdot)$].

Comment: Nice that is very elegant !

Comment: Well, in fact it's a quite well-known method...